# Writing XSLT for source and target XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a source and target XML and have to write XSLT for transformation. I have difficulty in matching components for the XSLT for Y part in target xml.

The source xml is:

```
<A id="123" name="a">
    <B>
        <d id="p123" name="one">
            <f>Hello</f>
            <e ref="c123" />
        </d>
        <d id="p234" name="two">
            <f>Hello</f>
            <e ref="c234" />
            <e ref="c123" />
        </d>
    </B>
    <C>
        <e id="c123" type="paragraph"><text>Dummy Text</text></e>
        <e id="c234" type="link" url="google.com"/>
    </C>
</A>
```

The target xml is:

```
<X id="123" name="a">
    <Y id="p123" name="one">
        <f>Hello</f>
        <content id="c123" type="TEXT"><text>Dummy Text</text></content >
    </Y>
    <Y id="p234" name="two">
        <f>Hello</f>
        <content id="c234" type="link" url="google.com"/>
        <content id="c123" type="paragraph"><text>Dummy Text</text></content >
    </Y>
</X>
```

The XSLT is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl= "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="A" />
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="A" >
     <X id="@id" name="@name">
            <xsl:for-each select="A/B/d" >
             <Y id="@id" name="@name">

             </Y>
            </xsl:for-each>
     </X>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where is the `type="TEXT"` supposed to come from if `<e />` appears under both, `id="123"` and `id="234"`?

Comment: This seems very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61107422/xml-cross-references-in-xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this XSLT-1.0 stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl= "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="A" >
      <X id="{@id}" name="{@name}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="B/d" />
      </X>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="d" >
      <Y id="{@id}" name="{@name}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="f" />      
        <xsl:apply-templates select="e" />
      </Y>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="e" >
      <content>
        <xsl:copy-of select="/A/C/e[current()/@ref = @id]/@* | /A/C/e[current()/@ref = @id]/*" />
      </content>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<X id="123" name="a">
  <Y id="p123" name="one">
    <f>Hello</f>
    <content id="c123" type="paragraph">
      <text>Dummy Text</text>
    </content>
  </Y>
  <Y id="p234" name="two">
    <f>Hello</f>
    <content id="c234" type="link" url="google.com"/>
    <content id="c123" type="paragraph">
      <text>Dummy Text</text>
    </content>
  </Y>
</X>
```

The first `<content>`'s type is not "TEXT", because that would have been irregular. I assumed that you want a regular output.

---

If speed is critical, you can realize the optimizations suggested in the comments:

- Add an `xsl:key` at the top-level:

  ```
  <xsl:key name="ids" match="/A/C/e" use="@id" />
  ```
- And access it in the `e` template

  ```
  <xsl:copy-of select="key('ids',current()/@ref)/@* | key('ids',current()/@ref)/@*" />
  ```

This still performs the lookup twice. If that disturbs you, you can cache the result of the `xsl:key` in a variable.

Comment: This is very inefficient. You are performing the same lookup twice, once for the attributes and once for the elements. AND the lookup itself is less efficient because it does not use a key.

Answer (score 0):

Parts of your required mapping are missing in your question, but I think you can start from this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl= "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="A" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="A" >
     <X id="{@id}" name="{@name}">
        <xsl:for-each select="B/d" >
             <Y id="{@id}" name="{@name}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="f"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="e">
                    <content id="{@ref}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
             </Y>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </X>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZXVEU

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that uses xsl:key if efficiency is a concern. It's also 100% push style.

It's a little verbose, but also pretty simple to follow/maintain.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="content" match="e[@id]" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="A">
    <X>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|B/*"/>
    </X>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="d">
    <Y>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Y>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="e[@ref]">
    <content>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('content',@ref)"/>
    </content>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="e[@id]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZXVEV